# What is cloud mining?

Tags: cloud-mining

Okay I am mining with coinpot. I am just a low user I guess you could say. My name is Seth and I just started into this mining game as I call it. I was just wondering if there is some kind of resource that explains mining in ENGLISH!! I have trouble with all the terms and stuff. Another thing if anyone can give pointers about coinpot that would be great as well.

Answer (score 1):

Cloud mining can mean a couple of things. 1) mining using a cloud server 2) browser based mining - e.g. javascript mining in a web page.

Coinpot falls into the latter e.g. browser based mining. It also claims tiny amounts of real cryptocurrencies from public faucets (which are for gifting small amounts of a currency for user adoption). You'd do better financially by wandering the streets looking for cents than using Coinpot IMO.

If you want to get into mining, download a miner such as xmr-stak and mine to one of the many mining pools.